# CSS - How to specify CSS so that the page doesn't have horizontal bar when the user zooms the page?

Tags: css, css-sprites

Please refer to http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/intro.html
When the user zooms the page, there is no horizontal bar introduced on the bottom.

I would like to know how to design a two-column page with this properties.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, they simply have not set a min-width, just a max-width. So the browser is pretty much free to reposition everything.

In a two column layout you should probably use percentages for your column (i.e. main column 70% and navigation column 30%), that should work fine for you.

A good starting point would be http://tutorialblog.org/fluid-fixed-and-elastic-web-design-explained/